# How to use HashMap to use return a same Object for Same Key from a Cache?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have the following set of classes (along with a failing unit test):

Sprocket:

```
public class Sprocket {
    private int serialNumber;

    public Sprocket(int serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "sprocket number " + serialNumber;
    }
}
```

SlowSprocketFactory:

```
public class SlowSprocketFactory {
    private final AtomicInteger maxSerialNumber = new AtomicInteger();

    public Sprocket createSprocket() {
        // clang, click, whistle, pop and other expensive onomatopoeic operations
        int serialNumber = maxSerialNumber.incrementAndGet();
        return new Sprocket(serialNumber);
    }

    public int getMaxSerialNumber() {
        return maxSerialNumber.get();
    }
}
```

SprocketCache:

```
public class SprocketCache {

    private SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory;
    private Sprocket sprocket;

    public SprocketCache(SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory) {
        this.sprocketFactory = sprocketFactory;
    }

    public Sprocket get(Object key) {
        if (sprocket == null) {
            sprocket = sprocketFactory.createSprocket();
        }

        return sprocket;
    }
}
```

TestSprocketCache unit test:

```
public class TestSprocketCache {

    private SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory = new SlowSprocketFactory();

    @Test
    public void testCacheReturnsASprocket() {
        SprocketCache cache = new SprocketCache(sprocketFactory);
        Sprocket sprocket = cache.get("key");
        assertNotNull(sprocket);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCacheReturnsSameObjectForSameKey() {
        SprocketCache cache = new SprocketCache(sprocketFactory);

        Sprocket sprocket1 = cache.get("key");
        Sprocket sprocket2 = cache.get("key");

        assertEquals("cache should return the same object for the same key", sprocket1, sprocket2);
        assertEquals("factory's create method should be called once only", 1, sprocketFactory.getMaxSerialNumber());
    }
}
```

The TestSprocketCache unit test always returns a green bar even if I change the following as follows:

```
Sprocket sprocket1 = cache.get("key");
Sprocket sprocket2 = cache.get("pizza");
```

Am guessing that I have to use a HashMap.contains(key) inside SprocketCache.get() method but can't seem to figure the logic.

Comment: You *aren't* using a `HashMap`, and that's the *problem.* Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having here is that your `get(Object)` implementation only allows one instance to be created:

```
    public Sprocket get(Object key) {
        // Creates object if it doesn't exist yet
        if (sprocket == null) { 
            sprocket = sprocketFactory.createSprocket();
        }

        return sprocket;
    }
```

This is a typical lazy-loading instantiation *singleton* pattern. If you invoke `get` again, an instance will be assigned to `sprocket` and it will skip the instantiation completely. Note that you don't even use the `key` parameter at all, so it does not affect anything.

Using a `Map` would indeed be one way to achieve your objective:

```
public class SprocketCache {

    private SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory;
    private Map<Object, Sprocket> instances = new HashMap<Object, Sprocket>();

    public SprocketCache(SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory) {
        this.sprocketFactory = sprocketFactory;
    }

    public Sprocket get(Object key) {
        if (!instances.containsKey(key)) {
            instances.put(sprocket);
        }

        return instances.get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your current Cache implementation does not rely on key, so no wonder it always returns same cached-once value.

If you want to store different values for keys, and assuming you want it to be thread safe, you might end up doing something like this:

```
public class SprocketCache {

    private SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Sprocket> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<?>();

    public SprocketCache(SlowSprocketFactory sprocketFactory) {
        this.sprocketFactory = sprocketFactory;
    }

    public Sprocket get(Object key) {
        if (!cache.contains(key)) {
            // we only wan't acquire lock for cache seed operation rather than for every get
            synchronized (key){                     
                // kind of double check locking to make sure no other thread has populated cache while we were waiting for monitor to be released
                if (!cache.contains(key)){ 
                    cache.putIfAbsent(key, sprocketFactory.createSprocket());
                }
            } 
        }
        return cache.get(key);
    }
}
```

Couple important side notes:

- you'll need CocncurrentHashMap to ensure happens-before paradigm and so other thread will instantly see if cache has been filled;
- new cache value creation has to be synchronized so each concurrent
  thread won't generate it's own value, overriding previous values during race condition;
- synchronization is quite expensive so we only wan't to engage it when needed, and due to same race condition you might get several threads holding monitor at the same time. That is why another check is required AFTER synchronized block to make sure that other thread hasn't already filled that value.